# Cakephp URL while Paginating with search

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I've a simple cakephp app with search and pagination. I'm using GET as type for forms.

When I click search with desired filters, paginated results are shown. I get desired results when I move across pages (with URL being modified with desired index of page number and filtered parameters).

Say I'm on page:4 of paginated search results. Now when I modify some search filter and hit search button again with page:4 shown, if results have less records (say that can be accommodated on one page), I get error - unable to find xxxxxx on server. (....../page:4/.... doesn't exist)..

Please help!

Comment: It's an obvious usability point to show users page 1 whenever the filters change.

Comment: I use pagination + cakedc search plugin - and this always automatically jumps to page 1 for changed filters. So I cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2):

when you press search usually you want to reset all or same of the paginator parameters

I guess that in your view you just did

```
echo $this->Form->create('Model');
```

in this way cake assume that the action of the form is the url of the page you are in

but you can set the url of the form this way

```
echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('url' => array('page' => 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it as follows

```
$url = array('controller' => 'cc', 'action' => 'aa') + $this->request->params['pass'];
echo $this->Form->create(null, array('type' => 'get','url' => $url));
```

Thanks for your help.