# pagination cakephp 2 modified query

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4

I want to filter pagination. if i am in page 1 and i modify the query it works fine, but in page 2 the query built is

```
SELECT .... LIMIT 40,20
```

As I have only one page it fails as the result is empty.
How do I force back to search from page 1 with the pagination?
My code is

```
$conditions = array('transaction LIKE' => '%' . 
              $this->request->data['User']['trans_id'] . '%');
$this->set('deposits', $this->paginate($conditions));
```

I read in the doc of pagination I can use `try catch` for `$this->paginate($conditions)`, but not sure how to have in the catch the redirect.

Comment: As far as I understand, you need pagination with filter parameters? like this one http://detas.ba/satovi/od:64.00/do:360.00 ?

Comment: yes exactly like that. how did you redirect when you click on the search back to page 1?

Comment: I think that your problem is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532869/cakephp-url-while-paginating-with-search/23534185#23534185) question

Comment: @SelaYair , arilia gave a simple answer

Comment: that's cool. @arilia indeed gave good answer. what I changed now is that the action of the form doesn't have all the trail of the page and that solved the problem. I didn't think about it before. Thanks

Comment: also consider using cakedc search behavior and you'll not need to do this for every form. Also you don't have to create manually the conditions